# loop copy paste randomly leaving out data

Tags: vba, excel, loops

has anyone had an issue in excel vba where a loop to copy and paste rows and check for certain criteria sometimes leaves out information and after i try to debug and run through it works fine

I have a loop

```
For rnum = 3 To LastRow
    'if all cells are equal to the Comboboxes then copy and paste the row
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    If Sheets("Revised Budget").Cells(rnum, 1).Value = BUval And _
            Sheets("Revised Budget").Cells(rnum, 2).Value = TeamLocVal And _
            Sheets("Revised Budget").Cells(rnum, 3).Value = YrVal And _
            Sheets("Revised Budget").Cells(rnum, 9).Value = InstVal Then

        Sheets("Revised Budget").Range(Cells(rnum, 1), Cells(rnum, 12)).Copy
        NewWkbk.Sheets("Actual").Activate

        If NewWkbk.Sheets("Actual").Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
            NewWkbk.Sheets("Actual").Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        Else
            NewWkbk.Sheets("Actual").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        End If

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If

Next rnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your variables strings or integers?
If any of them are strings you can try making sure it's not an issue with capitalization on your string matches.

```
 ucase(Sheets("Revised Budget").Cells(rnum, 3).Value) = ucase(YrVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider updating all of your `.value` to `.value2`. I was running into a (potentially) similar issue, and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out through some more research.  The page in which the macro was running through had data that was filtered.  I put in a code that would ShowAllData and I believe that should fix the issue.